# Why am I getting "too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders"? Where is my infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, sorting, datatable

my below code runs, but I get the "too many re-renders" error. I am not sure why. If I take out the double switch and just base it on one unit, say price, then it works. However, I cannot find where my code is causing that infinite loop. Internet say somewhere I maybe using the useState incorrectly. Any help is appreciated. I'm a rookie, so please understand I maybe doing something boneheaded! Anyway to learn is awesome! Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import TableSortLabel from "@mui/material/TableSortLabel";
import { useState } from "react";


function createData(number, item, qty, price) {
  return { number, item, qty, price };
}

const rows = [
  createData(1, "Apple", 5, 3),
  createData(2, "Orange", 2, 2),
  createData(3, "Grapes", 3, 1),
  createData(4, "Tomato", 2, 1.6),
  createData(5, "Mango", 1.5, 4)
];

export default function SortedTable() {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(rows);
  const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection] = useState("asc");
  const [orderUnit, setOrderUnit] = useState("number");

  const sortArray = (arr, orderBy, orderUn) => {
    switch (orderUn) {
      case "number": 
      default:
        switch (orderBy) {
          case "asc":
          default:
            return arr.sort((a, b) =>
              a.number > b.number ? 1 : b.number > a.number ? -1 : 0
            );
          case "desc":
            return arr.sort((a, b) =>
              a.number > b.number ? 1 : b.number > a.number ? -1 : 0
            );
        }
      case "item": 
      switch (orderBy) {
        case "asc":
        default:
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.item > b.item ? 1 : b.item > a.item ? -1 : 0
          );
        case "desc":
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.item < b.item ? 1 : b.item < a.item ? -1 : 0
          );
      }
      case "qty": 
      switch (orderBy) {
        case "asc":
        default:
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.qty > b.qty ? 1 : b.qty > a.qty ? -1 : 0
          );
        case "desc":
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.qty < b.qty ? 1 : b.qty < a.qty ? -1 : 0
          );
      }
      case "price": 
      switch (orderBy) {
        case "asc":
        default:
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.price > b.price ? 1 : b.price > a.price ? -1 : 0
          );
        case "desc":
          return arr.sort((a, b) =>
            a.price < b.price ? 1 : b.price < a.price ? -1 : 0
          );
      }
    }
  };
 


  const handleSortRequest = (unit) => {
    setOrderUnit(orderUnit === unit); 
    setRowData(sortArray(rows, orderDirection, orderUnit));
    setOrderDirection(orderDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table" >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center" onClick={handleSortRequest("number")}><TableSortLabel active={true} direction={orderDirection}>
              S.No
            </TableSortLabel></TableCell>

            <TableCell align="center" onClick={handleSortRequest("item")}><TableSortLabel active={true} direction={orderDirection}>
              Item
            </TableSortLabel></TableCell>

            <TableCell align="center" onClick={handleSortRequest("qty")}><TableSortLabel active={true} direction={orderDirection}>
              Quantity&nbsp;(kg)
            </TableSortLabel></TableCell>

            <TableCell align="center" onClick={handleSortRequest("price")}>
              <TableSortLabel active={true} direction={orderDirection}>
                Price&nbsp;($)
              </TableSortLabel>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rowData.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.number}>
              <TableCell width="100" component="td" scope="row" align="center">
                {row.number}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.item}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.qty}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.price}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

I am trying to make it so that each column is sortable based on which one is clicked. Bonus question, why are my headers not matching up with my columns below when rendered.

Comment: You call `handleSortRequest` multiple times on every render. Instead of `handleSortRequest("qty")` use `() => handleSortRequest("qty")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function reference instead of invoking the function directly.
This way, the function will be invoked only when the event happens, rather than immediately when the component renders.

```
onClick={() => handleSortRequest("item")}
```

I also refactor your sortArray function for readable. If it is wrong. Pls Don't bother with it. :D

```
    const sortArray = useCallback((arr, orderBy, orderUn) => {
    const compare = (a, b, prop, order) => {
      if (order === "asc") {
        return a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : b[prop] > a[prop] ? -1 : 0;
      } else {
        return a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : b[prop] < a[prop] ? -1 : 0;
      }
    };

    switch (orderUn) {
      case "number":
      default:
        return arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b, "number", orderBy));

      case "item":
        return arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b, "item", orderBy));

      case "qty":
        return arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b, "qty", orderBy));

      case "price":
        return arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b, "price", orderBy));
    }
  }, []);
```

Use useCallback to prevent re-render unnecessary if dependency not change

```
const handleSortRequest = useCallback(
    (unit) => {
      setOrderUnit(orderUnit === unit);
      setRowData(sortArray(rows, orderDirection, orderUnit));
      setOrderDirection(orderDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc");
    },
    [orderDirection, orderUnit, sortArray]
  );
```

Hope these help you.

Comment: This worked minus the callback. However leaving my handleSortRequest as is, but changing the other two pieces made it work! Thank you so much! Any chance you know why when I run it, my headers only span the first column, and then the other columns are far right of table?

Comment: actualy, it is only sorting by the number with this code, not the column chosen, but I don't know if that is based on my header issue I mentioned in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my logic is quite different. useEffect hook is used to perform a side effect when orderUnit or orderDirection changes. It updates the rowData using the sortArray function.

codesandBox link is [Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sorting-86ktn7?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A48%2C39)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import TableSortLabel from "@mui/material/TableSortLabel";

function createData(number, item, qty, price) {
  return { number, item, qty, price };
}

const rows = [
  createData(1, "Apple", 5, 3),
  createData(2, "Orange", 2, 2),
  createData(3, "Grapes", 3, 1),
  createData(4, "Tomato", 2, 1.6),
  createData(5, "Mango", 1.5, 4),
];

const sortArray = (arr, orderBy, orderDirection) => {
  return [...arr].sort((a, b) => {
    const comparison =
      a[orderBy] > b[orderBy] ? 1 : b[orderBy] > a[orderBy] ? -1 : 0;
    return orderDirection === "asc" ? comparison : -comparison;
  });
};

export default function SortedTable() {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(rows);
  const [orderDirection, setOrderDirection] = useState("asc");
  const [orderUnit, setOrderUnit] = useState("number");

  useEffect(() => {
    setRowData((prevRows) => sortArray(prevRows, orderUnit, orderDirection));
  }, [orderUnit, orderDirection]);

  const handleSortRequest = (unit) => {
    setOrderUnit(unit);
    setOrderDirection((prevDirection) =>
      prevDirection === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    );
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell
              align="center"
              onClick={() => handleSortRequest("number")}
            >
              <TableSortLabel
                active={orderUnit === "number"}
                direction={orderDirection}
              >
                S.No
              </TableSortLabel>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center" onClick={() => handleSortRequest("item")}>
              <TableSortLabel
                active={orderUnit === "item"}
                direction={orderDirection}
              >
                Item
              </TableSortLabel>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center" onClick={() => handleSortRequest("qty")}>
              <TableSortLabel
                active={orderUnit === "qty"}
                direction={orderDirection}
              >
                Quantity (kg)
              </TableSortLabel>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell
              align="center"
              onClick={() => handleSortRequest("price")}
            >
              <TableSortLabel
                active={orderUnit === "price"}
                direction={orderDirection}
              >
                Price ($)
              </TableSortLabel>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rowData.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.number}>
              <TableCell width="100" component="td" scope="row" align="center">
                {row.number}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.item}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.qty}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.price}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```